# I am having trouble char array in java

Tags: java, arrays, char

I wrote this code. My aim is to write the string in char.
But i'm getting ArrayIndexOfBoundsException error.

```
public class Charwork {
    char[] letter;
    int keepInt;
    public Charwork()
    {
        letter = new char[keepInt]; 
    }

    public void copy(String nameToCoppy)
    {
        this.keepInt = nameToCoppy.length();
        System.out.println(this.keepInt);
        for(int x = 0; x < this.keepInt;x++)
        {
            letter[x] = nameToCoppy.charAt(x);
            System.out.println(letter[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `keepInt` has a different value in the constructor than in `copy` (also why are you instantiating the array in the constructor and not in the `copy` method?)

Comment: What method can I follow to be successful?

Comment: moving `letter = new char[keepInt];` from the constructor to after the line `this.keepInt = nameToCoppy.length();` should fix your error

Comment: Presumably this is a learning exercise, but if not see: [String.toCharArray()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray())

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is your array is instantiated with a int that is null or 0. Moving that one line in your constructor to the copy function after getting string length should do the trick.

```
public Charwork()
{

}

public void copy(String nameToCoppy)
{
    this.keepInt = nameToCoppy.length();
    letter = new char[keepInt]; 
    System.out.println(this.keepInt);
    for(int x = 0; x < this.keepInt;x++)
    {
        letter[x] = nameToCoppy.charAt(x);
        System.out.println(letter[x]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You create an object `Charwork`while instantiating variable `char[] letter` with length `keepInt` - but `keepInt` is zero at the moment, beacuse int is primitive and instantinated with default 0 value.

Then, in `copy` method you change value of `keepInt`,  but that's irrelevant, because an array `char[] letter` is already set with length 0.